# Load/Remove Css Dynamically when need

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have modal, when that open at the time i want to load my css file and after close the modal loaded css file has been remove from the page.

I am working on e-commerce site that page contain `bootstrap version 3.2.0` from starting, now i have create add to cart modal that contain `bootstrap version 3.3.6` so, i want to load `bootstrap v3.3.6` only when modal open and remove when close.

is that idea in jquery?

Answer (score 3):

I hope you get event of popup open and close.

When popup open

```
jQuery('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" id="bt-removable-css">');
```

When poup close

```
jQuery('#bt-removable-css').remove();
```

Comment: This will indeed add to the page the CSS file but will not remove the file. it will only remove the CSS class

Comment: It will remove whole css, `jQuery("#bt-removable-css").removeClass("class_name");` this will remove the class.

Comment: It will remove whole css, `jQuery("#bt-removable-css").removeClass("class_name");` this will remove the class.

Comment: Sorry you are right! I did not scroll completely to the right and therefore I did not see the id attribute within the link. I am sorry! Your answer is correct

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know this answer already. I want better like, $.getScript and something else. +1 for answer and thanks again for response